# Can the Central Limit Theorem be used in this case?

Tags: standard-error, central-limit-theorem

A student investigating study habits asks a simple random sample of 16 students at her large high school how many minutes they spent on their Math homework the previous night. Suppose the actual parameter values for this variable are $\mu= 45$  minutes and $\sigma = 15$ minutes. Which of the following best describes what we know about the sampling distribution of means for the student's sample?

Apparently the answer to this question is $\mu_x = 45;$ $\sigma_\bar{x}= 3.75;$  shape of distribution unknown.
In our class, the general rule of thumb is that we can only use the CLT if $n\gt 30.$ Hence, why the shape of the distribution is unknown. However, the $3.75$ is what I have a problem with: it comes from the formula $$\sigma_\bar{x}= \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}.$$
But how can this formula be used if the CLT doesn't apply? After all, this formula does come from the formal statement of the CLT.

Comment: To give some perspective, your rule of thumb isn't generally correct anyway.  So forget about the CLT altogether and consider what information a mean and standard deviation can give you.

Comment: Regarding your premises: The $\sigma/\sqrt{n}$ thing is not really *part of* the central limit theorem; it's a more basic result that some versions of the CLT rely on, a consequence of [basic properties of variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Basic_properties) and the assumption of independence. I highly recommend you read what the [CLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) actually says (at least the classic form), and not rely much on the information many textbooks give (many of the authors appear never to have sighted any version of an actual CLT in their life).

Answer (score 1):

The formula that the standard error of the sample mean is $\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$ can be shown without normality assumption and doesn't require the CLT to apply.

The formula just requires independently identically distributed (i.i.d.) observations and $\sigma^2<\infty$ (assuming that $\sigma^2$ denotes the variance of a single observation).

Comment: True and useful: but how does it address the key question of "how can this formula be used"?

Comment: I added what the formula requires. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, but that goes to the assumptions rather than to the application.  I believe the OP is asking something like "since I can't assume the sampling distribution is Normal, of what value are the sample mean and sample error?  How can I interpret them or make decisions using them?"

Comment: That isn't part of the cited question of which the OP was discussing the answer. Anyway, if this is also of interest, the OP can tell us, and maybe someone else can chip in.

Comment: The question being asked here is *not* the cited question: that was presented only for context.  The question is posed in the last paragraph.